# Entity Frame Code First The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys

**Database build error:**

One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

AccountLinkPermission_AccountLink_Target_AccountLinkPermission_AccountLink_Source: : The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.

**User class:**

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        AccountLinks = new HashSet<AccountLink>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AccountLink> AccountLinks { get; set; }
}
```

**Guest class:**

```
public class Guest
{
    public Guest()
    {
        AccountLinks = new HashSet<AccountLink>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int GuestID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AccountLink> AccountLinks { get; set; }
}
```

**AccountLink class:**

```
public class AccountLink
    {
        public AccountLink()
        {
            AccountLinkPermissions = new HashSet<AccountLinkPermission>();
        }

        public AccountLink(int userID, int guestID)
        {
            this.UserID = userID;
            this.GuestID = guestID;
        }

        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int AccountLinkID { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
        public int GuestID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserID")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("GuestID")]
        public virtual Guest Guest { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AccountLinkPermission> AccountLinkPermissions { get; set; }
    }
```

**AccountLinkPermission class:**

```
public class AccountLinkPermission
{
    public AccountLinkPermission(int accountLinkID, int permissionID)
    {
        this.AccountLinkID = accountLinkID;
        this.PermissionID = permissionID;
    }

    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int AccountLinkID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int PermissionID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AccountLinkID")]
    public virtual AccountLink AccountLink { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PermissionID")]
    public virtual Permission Permission { get; set; }
}
```

**Permission class:**

```
public class Permission
{
    public Permission()
    {
        AccountLinkPermissions = new HashSet<AccountLinkPermission>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int PermissionID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AccountLinkPermission> AccountLinkPermissions { get; set; }
}
```

**Problem:**

It wont let me put a foreign key between **AccountLinkPermission**, AccountLinkID and **AccountLink**, AccountLinkID. If I remove the ForeignKey attribute the database builds, but without a foreign key between these two.

Why in world is this not working? It's driving me crazy. PLEASE please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why I got this error message was because AccountLink had three primary keys. Because I was only declaring one foreign key from AccountLinkPermission to AccountLink, (AccountLinkID), it failed. I had to set Foreignkey for UserID and GuestID aswell.

Also, if you are using multiple foreign keys linked to the same table, EF is not able to determine by convention which navigation properties belongs together. Instead of using the property [ForeignKey] I had to use **[InverseProperty]**, which defines the navigation property on the other end of the relationship.

**Heres what's changed:**

**AccountLink:**

```
public class AccountLink
{
    public AccountLink()
    {
        AccountLinkPermissionAccountLinkID = new HashSet<AccountLinkPermission>();
        AccountLinkPermissionUserID = new HashSet<AccountLinkPermission>();
        AccountLinkPermissionGuestID = new HashSet<AccountLinkPermission>();
    }

    public AccountLink(int userID, int guestID)
    {
        AccountLinkPermissionAccountLinkID = new HashSet<AccountLinkPermission>();
        AccountLinkPermissionUserID = new HashSet<AccountLinkPermission>();
        AccountLinkPermissionGuestID = new HashSet<AccountLinkPermission>();
        this.UserID = userID;
        this.GuestID = guestID;
    }

    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int AccountLinkID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int GuestID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GuestID")]
    public virtual Guest Guest { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AccountLinkPermission> AccountLinkPermissionAccountLinkID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AccountLinkPermission> AccountLinkPermissionUserID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AccountLinkPermission> AccountLinkPermissionGuestID { get; set; }
}
```

**AccountLinkPermission:**

```
public class AccountLinkPermission
        {
            public AccountLinkPermission(int accountLinkID, int userID, int guestID, int permissionID)
            {
                this.AccountLinkID = accountLinkID;
                this.UserID = userID;
                this.GuestID = guestID;
                this.PermissionID = permissionID;
            }

            [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
            public int AccountLinkID { get; set; }
            [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
            public int UserID { get; set; }
            [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
            public int GuestID { get; set; }
            [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
            public int PermissionID { get; set; }

            [InverseProperty("AccountLinkPermissionAccountLinkID")]
            public virtual AccountLink AccountLink { get; set; }

            [InverseProperty("AccountLinkPermissionUserID")]
            public virtual AccountLink AccountLinkUser { get; set; }

            [InverseProperty("AccountLinkPermissionGuestID")]
            public virtual AccountLink AccountLinkGuest { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey("PermissionID")]
            public virtual Permission Permission { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its to do with your data annotations.You don't mark your foreign key properties with [Key]

AccountLink.cs

```
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int AccountLinkID { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int GuestID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GuestID")]
    public virtual Guest Guest { get; set; }
```

AccountLinkPermission.cs

```
[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
public int AccountLinkPermissionID { get; set; }
[Column(Order = 1)]
public int AccountLinkID { get; set; }
[Column(Order = 2)]
public int PermissionID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("AccountLinkID")]
public virtual AccountLink AccountLink { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("PermissionID")]
public virtual Permission Permission { get; set; }
```

Everything else looks ok. Hope that helps

Comment: Hey! Are you sure you dont have to specificy column with Key? I Get this error now:

AccountLinkPermission' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType. AccountLinkPermission: EntityType: EntitySet 'AccountLinkPermission' is based on type 'AccountLinkPermission' that has no keys defined.

Comment: sorry my bad ;) I deleted the Primary Key from AccountLinkPermission by mistake. Please see edit

Comment: Thanks but I'm confused now.. It is supposed to be three primary keys in Accountlink and two primary keys in AccountLinkPermissions. What will this do? Won't it be one primary key in each of these tables now? Thanks

Comment: why do you need 3 PK's in AccountLink? Both relationships specified are one to many ie a single AccountLink has multiple users and guests

Comment: I want 3 PKS because I don't want duplicated links. If UserID and GuestID is not primaries duplication can occur. Am I way over in the fantasy land now or do I have a point:)?